# How to put a comma delimited list in the select list of an insert statement @Tablevariable

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this

```
    TableX
    Id      ServiceID
    1       10
    1       20
    1       30
    2       15
    2       25 
    2       35
```

and a table variable @TableA

```
declare @TableA table
(
 Id              int primary key,
 ServiceIdList   varchar(max)
)
```

i need @TableA to look like this

```
    Id     ServiceIdList
    1       10,20,30
    2       15,25,35
```

but I can't figure out the syntax for insert statement. I'd like to use COALESCE, as opposed to STUFF if possible. Anyone know how to do this?
Something like

```
Insert @TableA
select distinct X.Id,
       coalesce(@TableA.ServiceIdList + ',', '') + cast(TableX.ServiceId as varchar)
from   TableX X
group by X.Id, X.ServiceId
```

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: `I need @TableA to look like this` ... no you don't; storing CSV in your tables should be avoided, there is nothing wrong with your original normalized table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I think it's a bit rich to assume that there is nothing wrong with the original normalized table without some context of what the author is trying to achieve. Given the required format, I guess it is for display purposes only. And since the request is put the result in into a table variable, that means its temporary anyway.

Comment: @Adrian If for display purposes, then I retract what I said.  But putting CSV into a table is a common beginner's mistake, and I thought I would leave a comment to this effect.

Answer (score 2):

```
Insert @TableA
Select A.ID
      ,ServiceIdList  = (Select Stuff((Select Distinct ',' +cast(ServiceID as varchar(25)) From YourTable Where ID=A.ID For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') )
 From (Select Distinct ID From YourTable ) A
```

Returns

```
ID  ServiceIdList
1   10,20,30
2   15,25,35
```

Comment: Thank you John, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @N.Mendenhall Happy to help